# Missing Section in POLINK warning from HLA code

Tags: hla

I have an error that I looked around the internet quite a bit yet I have yet to find a real solution to this problem. Here is the error message I get from my computer (Win 7):

```
POLINK: warning: /SECTION:.bss ignored; section is missing.
```

With this error, obviously comes some code. So what I am trying to do with the code is see what happens wham you mix signed and unsigned variables in the same calculation. I am sure this error shows up in other situations as well, but I haven't bothered to do too much about it. Anyways, here's the code:

```
  program example;
#include ("stdlib.hhf")

static 
    unsigned: uns16;
    dummy:byte;

begin example;

    stdout.put ("Enter an int between 32 768 and 65 

525");
stdin.getu16();
mov (ax, unsigned);

stdout.put  (
"You entered",
unsigned,
". If this were a signed int, it would be: "
);
stdout.puti16 (unsigned);
stdout.newln();

end example;
```

Any help would be appreciated as to where this problem  originates so anything would be appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Firstly this is not an error message it is a warning.

As evident from POLINK: ***warning***: /SECTION:.bss ignored; section is missing.

The linker called POLINK complains that the BSS section is missing, because in the assembly your HLA code snippet generates it is.

In order to make it go away, you can change HLA to use another linker that doesn't generate the warning message or you can add HLA code which populates the BSS with a dummy or placeholder variable.

The code to add would be

```
storage
  dummy:byte;
```

before the begin example line.

**Reference** 
 - [POLINK: warning: /SECTION:.bss ignored; section is missing. from MASM forums](http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?PHPSESSID=786dd40408172108b65a5a36b09c88c0&topic=2489.0;prev_next=prev)