# POLINK: warning: /SECTION:.bss ignored; section is missing

Tags: hla

I'm receiving a warning when trying to run a hello world script.

I'm just curious to see if there was a quick fix to remove this warning. I read somewhere to change the linker it's using but not sure how to do that. Thanks for any input!

`POLINK: warning: /SECTION:.bss ignored; section is missing.`

```
c:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hla>path=c:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hla;c:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hla;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hla;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;C:\Users\thegu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\thegu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;C:\Users\thegu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\thegu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\thegu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\thegu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.3.1\bin;;C:\Users\thegu\AppData\Roaming\npm;

c:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hla>set lib=c:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hla\hlalib

c:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hla>set hlainc=c:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hla\include

c:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hla>set hlalib=c:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hla\hlalib\hlalib.lib

c:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hla>cd ..\hlahello

c:\TEMP\ASSEMBLY\hlahello>fhla hello
flat assembler  version 1.56
5 passes, 819 bytes.
POLINK: warning: /SECTION:.bss ignored; section is missing.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing Section in POLINK warning from HLA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587141/missing-section-in-polink-warning-from-hla-code)